# Implementing new Views which are downloadable separately from main android app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments

Hi is it possible in android to implement views or gui code which has its own layout xml files in a separate jar and have the main android app download them and load them dynamically? I understand that we can use PathClassLoader/DexClassLoader to load jar files dynamically but it seems that with any code that requires the layout.xml to display a view for example, requires a recompilation of the entire code base in order for the app to reference the new view code via R.id.newViewId. Is it possible for android to reference the layout.xml file in the jar without recompilation?

Similarly, how do game developers implement downloading new levels, for example, for users which have purchased them in app and dynamically loading them into the app (assuming that the new game levels require some layout.xml file)?

Comment: it is possible but it is very very heavy

Comment: What is the use case?

Comment: Hi Praveen, I have edited my post to include an example use case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible for android to reference the layout.xml file in the jar without recompilation?

No. First, Android does not use JAR resources. Second, Android resources have to be compiled into and packaged in the APK.

*You* are welcome to use JAR resources, but they will just be data files, not Android resources.

> assuming that the new game levels require some layout.xml file

I would sincerely hope that game levels are pure data, without any Java code. `DexClassLoader` is difficult to secure well.

If they, for some strange reason, insisted upon using a layout resource XML structure, they would have had to write their own parser for it to generate the corresponding Java objects.

Comment: So how does someone currently implement, for example, interactive animations, which is available for purchase in-app, to be made available to the app? The data would obviously be images/bitmaps which will just be data files as you have mentioned. but the "interactive" part would require code and that code has to be downloaded and loaded dynamically into the app right? Is that how it would work?

Comment: @lesley: I have no idea what you consider an "interactive animation" to be. Downloading code is difficult to secure properly, so I would hope that an "interactive animation" would be a data structure, describing the effect, that would be interpreted by code that already exists in the app.